# texts could not be included in Advanced tables in memoir class, why?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,adjustbox,array}

\begin{document}

\section{memoir Advanced Tables}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{
  *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]}
  *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}
}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Circles} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Geometric Orientation} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Shape Orientation}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} 
{\textbf{Circle location}} & {$R_y$} & {$P_a/Z$}  & {$G_{tn}/V$}  & {$a_{bn}^*$ (OR) $d_{gd}^*$} \\
\midrule
 & 5.64 & 2.12  & 0.5234 to 0.3154  & 1.354 to 5.159\\
\textbf{Full Circle} & 1.34 & 2.58  & 0.1827 to 0.5861  & 1.335 to 1.4564\\
 & 7.55 & 3.15  & 0.3068 to 0.7521  & 1.809 to 2.811\\
\midrule
 & 3.24 & 2.64  & -0.1052 to 0.2100 & 0.8358 to 1.556\\
\textbf{Half Circle} & 5.64 & 3.78 & -0.06201 to 0.1827 & 0.9876 to 1.1055\\
 & 4.56 & 7.78  & -0.8456 to 0.3261  & 1.7231 to 2.854 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
\label{table:My_caption}
\caption{Table for Circles and Geometries} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is attached below

[image]

Any good solution or suggestions is mostly welcome?

Comment: I think your problem comes from the fact that you are using an S table column with something other than just numbers in the last to columns. it is not related to the memoir class.

Comment: How to overcome the problem? By adopting to another different type of table without S table column

Comment: the `S` column is only for formatting numbers so they align properly using centred on the decimal point. in your example, only column 2 and 3 fit that category. column 1 should probably be a normal `l` column, while 4 and 5 may be simply `c`. If you want to centre on the "to" then it could be a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two numbers separated by ‘to’ in a numeric column. Use two columns with the separator defined in the table specification.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,adjustbox,array}

\begin{document}

\section{memoir Advanced Tables}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\sisetup{group-digits=integer}
\begin{tabular}
{
 l
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=-1.5]
 @{ to }
 S[table-format=1.4]
 S[table-format=1.4]
 @{ to }
 S[table-format=1.4]
}
\toprule
&&&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Orientation}\\
\cmidrule{4-7}
&&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Circles} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Geometric} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Shape} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} 
\textbf{Circle location} & {$R_y$} & {$P_a/Z$}  &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$G_{tn}/V$}  &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$a_{bn}^*$ (OR) $d_{gd}^*$} \\
\midrule
 & 5.64 & 2.12  & 0.5234 & 0.3154  & 1.354 & 5.159\\
\textbf{Full Circle} & 1.34 & 2.58  & 0.1827 & 0.5861  & 1.335 & 1.4564\\
 & 7.55 & 3.15  & 0.3068 & 0.7521  & 1.809 & 2.811\\
\midrule
 & 3.24 & 2.64  & -0.1052 & 0.2100 & 0.8358 & 1.556\\
\textbf{Half Circle} & 5.64 & 3.78 & -0.06201 & 0.1827 & 0.9876 & 1.1055\\
 & 4.56 & 7.78  & -0.8456 & 0.3261  & 1.7231 & 2.854 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
\caption{Table for Circles and Geometries} 
\label{table:My_caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Remember that the label should go *after* the caption.

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution @egreg and also thanks for ArTourter for his suggestions.